# Powers of elements in Group Theory (Indices)

Tags: group-theory

I'm having trouble proving that the properties of powers in integers holds for elements in a group as well.
The theorem says:

> Suppose $ g \in G$ and $m,n \in\Bbb Z_+$ Show that $$g^{m+n} = g^{m}*g^{n}$$

How do I prove it? I have an idea that induction should be used but what should be the base case?

Thanks!

Comment: Base case n=1 that should be enough then use associativity

Comment: Yes, I tried it through induction but couldn't decide on the base case so set m=1 along with n=1 and proceeded with the proof but wasn't too happy with it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it via induction.

Take $n=1$. Then it is obvious that $g^m* g=g^{m+1}$.

Assume that this equality it is true for $n$.

We will show that for $n+1$.

$$g^m*g^{n+1}=g^m(g^n*g)=(g^m*g^n)*g=g^{m+n}*g=g^{m+n+1}$$

Then just show that  $(g^m)^{-1}=(g^{-1})^m=g^{-m}$. for $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence, we can deduce this equality is true for all $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Can you please tell me why we have to show that (g^m)^-1 = g^(-m)? What does it have to do here in this proof?

Comment: we have not to show $(g^m)^{-1}=(g^-1)^m=g^{-m}$ for your question.

Comment: I mean it is also true for $\mathbb{Z}$ not just  for $\mathbb{Z}^+$

Comment: Yes, got it! Thank you :)